# Scanner throws when user input is a small float

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a project and I've found a bug that has been a recurring problem with some of my previous assignments. Basically, I have a method that prompts user input and then returns that value. I check to make sure the user has inputted a value greater than 0 and my code works as expected EXCEPT for really small negative or positive float values close to 0. Now, I believe it's because the variable I am setting this user input to is an integer so it's throwing when the value is a float... I could be totally wrong though, I'm still very new to programming.

Here is the user input code:

```
public static int userNumber(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = 0;

        while(n <= 0){
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer");
            n = input.nextInt();
        }

        return n;

    }
```

And this is the error it returns when a user enters 0.1523156:
0.1523156

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Lab5.userNumber(Lab5.java:22)
    at Lab5.main(Lab5.java:7)
```

I've tried closing the scanner but that also causes an error... Can someone help me understand what's going on? I want to prompt the user to enter a valid integer and if the input isn't valid, to continue prompting.

Thanks!

Comment: "*I believe it's because the variable I am setting this user input to is an integer so it's throwing when the value is a float*" you are correct. Asking for int (via `nextIng()`) but getting float is unexpected behavior which causes exception. "*I want to prompt the user to enter a valid integer...*" to help you we need to know how you want your application to react on floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner.nextInt()` throws `InputMismatchException` if the next token doesn't match the `Integer`.

As an option, before scanning the input, you can use a [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) method in order to check whether the input is a valid `Integer`.

Example:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    String msg = "Please, enter a positive Integer:";
    int n = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println(msg);
        // make the user keep entering the input until it's an Integer
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println(msg);
            sc.next();
        }
        n = sc.nextInt();
    }
    while (n <= 0); // run until the input is a positive Integer

    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use hasNextInt().

```
    int n=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(!input.hasNextInt() && n <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive Integer.");
        input.next();
    }
    n = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(n);
    input.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I didn't realize there was a "hasNextInt" object.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your help. It seems like the above code was working fine within my IDE but as soon as I ran it via cmd it wasn't working as intended. I have used your code and it seems to be exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `nextInt()` only if you are sure of user will input int only. As per javadoc of the method, it will throw exception if entered value can't be parsed to int:

`InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range`

You should rather use `next()` which will give you string, and then try to parse it until you get valid int.

```
public class InputRead {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("UserNumber entered:" + userNumber());
    }

    public static int userNumber(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = 0;

        while(n <= 0){
            try{
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer");
                String read = input.next();
                n = Integer.parseInt(read);
            } catch(NumberFormatException e){
                //ignore
            }
        }

        input.close();
        return n;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Solution using `hasNextInt()`:

```
public class InputIntRead {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("UserNumber entered:" + userNumber());
    }

    public static int userNumber(){

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String msg = "Please, enter a positive integer:";
            int n = 0;

            while(n <= 0){              
                System.out.println(msg);
                if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                    n = scanner.nextInt();
                } else {
                    scanner.next();
                }
            }

            return n;
        }
    }
}
```